# Fetching Data from 3 different tables based on Where Parameters - MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, select, inner-join

I need to Select the delegate’s no. & name along with the module’s code & name for delegates who have taken a module but have a grade below 40 ( in the 'take' table )

Here's a link to what i'm doing -  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3e2c26

please ignore how bad the original query is for now i'm just trying to get my head around it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the table and pick the columns

> ```
> SELECT d.no, d.name,m.code,m.name  FROM take t INNER JOIN delegate d ON d.no = t.no
> INNER JOIN module m ON m.code = t.code WHERE grade < 40
> ```
>
> ```
>   no | name | code | name   
> ---: | :--- | :--- | :------
> 2002 | Andy | A2   | ASP.NET
> 2002 | Andy | A3   | PHP
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4a7ecd63a7544093d8174b54878a357b)*